# Deciding std. deviation for policy network output?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, probability-distribution, proximal-policy-optimization

When I try to fit a Normal Distribution to the output of a policy network, for a continuous action space problem, what should be its standard deviation? mean for the distribution will directly be the output of the policy network.